# Oracle error : " java.sql.sqlexception no more data to read from socket"

Tags: sql, oracle, weblogic

Can someone please help fix this error :

> java.sql.sqlexception no more data to read from socket, I am using Oracle 12g and web server is weblogic. In Datasource configuration if i keep initial capacity equals max capacity then got this java.sql.sqlexception no more data to read from socket this error.

Answer (score 0):

As i understand, No more data to read from socket error is related to  the generic communications error.

This is usually seen as TNS (Transparent Network Substrate (TNS), a proprietary Oracle computer-networking technology, supports homogeneous peer-to-peer connectivity on top of other networking technologies such as TCP/IP, SDP and named pipes. TNS operates mainly for connection to Oracle databases) connectivity issues.

When you see this error on your Application error.log, then check your connection with the Oracle server. Probably the Application server is disconnected from Oracle Server.[1](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/fmw/wls/12c/04-ConfigDataSource/configds.html)

You can increase initialSize and maxActive size of connection pool on your Application.[2](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/ConsoleHelp/domain_jdbcconnectionpool_config_connections.html)

Even Though No more data to read from socket error is related with communication and network error, This error is reported as Oracle Bug in 11g. If you see this error in the 11g, then you may think to upgrade the database to 12c or 19c.